# Teminal ( -bash: create-react-app: command not found) seems bugs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, macos, module, terminal

Not able to run create-react-app on macos terminal, when I do run appears -bash:crate-react-app: command not found. Probably I have to change the path of node module from /usr/local/bin/npm to share/npm/lib. How to change the path so I could run create-ract-app or any other actions to solve the problem?

Comment: what's your question?

Comment: How are you trying to run create-react-app? Did you install it? How?

Comment: by running some command in the mac os terminal:  npm install -g start-react-app